# APP_ENV is not recognized in Windows Git Bash with PHPUnit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

With Symfony 4.2, Windows and Git Bash,

When I run this command, **it's OK**, my database `bublemeet_test` is updated :

```
APP_ENV=test php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

In my `test/` folder, I have `bootstrap.php` file :

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/../config/bootstrap.php';

if (isset($_ENV['APP_ENV'])) {
    passthru(sprintf(
        'APP_ENV=%s php "%s/../bin/console" cache:clear --no-warmup',
        $_ENV['APP_ENV'],
        __DIR__
    ));
}
```

But when I run this command :

```
./bin/phpunit
```

I have this error :

> 'APP_ENV' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
>   ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

Why APP_ENV is not recognized when I execute the `./bin/phpunit` command but is recognized when I update the database ?

Comment: I think passthru is running "cmd", not bash. Try some like `bash -c "APP_ENV=bla bla bla"` (take care of quotes)

Comment: Thanks very much, it's good ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/testing.html#customizing-database-url-environment-variables), you'll need to set the url in `.env.test` as below:

```
# .env.test
DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name_test"
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows `passthru` uses `cmd` not `bash`.

You can modify your code using same like

```
<?php

passthru(sprintf(
        'bash -c "APP_ENV=%s php \\"%s/../bin/console\\" cache:clear --no-warmup"',
        $_ENV['APP_ENV'],
        __DIR__
    ));
```